# How does the mount module work in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, mount

What does the `mount` module do exactly?

I have the following two steps in `shell`:

```
vi /etc/fstab
#edit an already existing entry in the file. The path of this entry is: /

mount -o remount /
```

I would like to perform these tasks on numerous machines thus I would like to use Ansible for the job. However I'm not sure Ansible performs the second step. Based on he documentation the `mount` module is rather an `fstab` editor. Or am I wrong?

While testing I saw that Ansible in fact edited `fstab` as I wanted, but I'm not sure if it did a `remount` to "activate" the changes. Ansible code:

```
  - name: Add userquota to fstab
    mount:
      path: /
      state: present
      opts: errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota
      fstype: ext4
      src: LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs
```

Is it enough in it self or do I need to perform he following step, too? Or does he previous step contains this command? Is it redundant or not?

```
  - name: Remount root filesystem
    shell: mount -o remount /
```

Answer (score 3):

> Q: "What does the mount module do exactly?"

A: Quoting from [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html#mount-control-active-and-configured-mount-points). Parameter state:

- **mounted**: The device will be actively mounted and appropriately configured in fstab...
- **unmounted**: The device will be unmounted without changing fstab.
- **present**: The device is to be configured in fstab and does not trigger or require a mount.
- **absent**: The device mount's entry will be removed from fstab and will also unmount the device ...

> Q: "Based on the documentation the mount module is rather an fstab editor. Or am I wrong?"

A: Yes. You're wrong.

> Q: "Ansible in fact edited fstab as I wanted, but I'm not sure if it did a remount to "activate" the changes. Do I need to perform *`shell: mount -o remount /`*? Or does the previous step contains this command? Is it redundant or not?

A: Yes. It is redundant. No. You don't have to remount the entry. When *`state: mounted`*, the entry has already been mounted, and the fstab entry hasn't changed then there is no reason to remount the entry. If the entry hasn't been mounted yet then *`state: mounted`* will mount it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change "state: present" to "state: mounted" and modify the name:

```
    - name: Add userquota to fstab and remount /
      mount:
        path: /
        state: mounted
        opts: errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota
        fstype: ext4
        src: LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs
```